# Base class returning pointer to the derived class without explicit casting in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I am interested in whether it is possible to return a pointer to the derived class from a method defined in the base class without explicitly casting it to the derived class. The idea is that the receiver receives a pointer to the derived class through a pointer to base class and treats it as if it were a derived class through polymorphism.

For example, it is possible to do this:

```
template<typename TClassType>
class A
{

public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<TClassType const> execute(void)
        {
            return std::shared_ptr<TClassType const>
                (static_cast<TClassType*>(this));
        }
};
```

Here, the derived class is being passed as the template argument.

However, what I would like to do is something similar to this:

```
template<typename TBaseClassType>
class A
{

public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<TBaseClassType const> execute(void)
        {
            return this;
        }
};
```

I would like to do it in such a way that the returned pointer to base is still polymorphic with respect to the original derived class. `TBaseClassType` could be class `A`, but could also be in between class `A` and the derived class in the inheritance tree, i.e. `A->TBaseClassType->Derived`. `Derived` is the class from which `execute()` is called.

Note 1: it has to be a pointer to const (can also be a const pointer to const).

Note 2: I understand why this particular solution cannot work and I am interested if anyone knows of ways around the problem, rather than the direct approach.

---

EDIT. The solution I decided to use is summarised in my last comment for the accepted answer.

Comment: The much bigger problem here is that you're trying to construct a shared pointer around an object that already exists..

Comment: I feel that you're into covariance (as with a `clone` function, say), but the question also has the XY-feel. Asking about imagined solution Y to real problem X. For covariance, with C++11 you can do man-in-the-middle inheritance with constructor argument forwarding, or just a macro to be used to reimplement the function in each new class. (It's possible to alternatively rely on dominance in virtual inheritance, but I don't recommend that.) Regarding the problem mentioned by @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you can use [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am aware that this is not, in general, a good style. I am currently thinking about a somewhat hypothetical solution to a particular type of pipeline interface. It seems that there are ways around using shared_ptr like shared_from_this (see above). Also, it is likely that I will need to manage the object using shared_ptr, as it is likely to have multiple 'connections' to it from various pipeline segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are covariant returntypes. This means that e.g. a `clone()` function can be defined to return a `base*` in the baseclass and to return a `derived*` in the derived class. This is not your problem though, because the two types `shared_ptr<base>` and `shared_ptr<derived>` are not covariant, they are completely unrelated. There are ways around that, but they require a bit of work:

```
class base
{
public:
    smart_ptr<base> clone() const
    { return smart_ptr<base>(this->do_clone()); }
private:
    virtual base* do_clone()
    { return new base(*this); }
};
```

As you see, the public function returning a smart pointer calls the private virtual function that returns a raw pointer and which can use covariant returntypes. Now the derived class:

```
class derived: public base
{
public:
    smart_ptr<derived> clone() const
    { return smart_ptr<derived>(this->do_clone()); }
private:
    virtual derived* do_clone()
    { return new derived(*this); }
};
```

This class pretty much contains the similar code, only that it derives from `base`. Now, if you have a reference (or pointer/smart pointer) to the derived class, calling `clone()` on it will give you a pointer of the right type. Calling it on a reference to the baseclass will give you a pointer who's static type is `base` but who's dynamic type is still the correct derived class. This works because the lookup of memberfunction stops in the most derived class that implements the function and then stops. So basically this is a mixture of overriding virtual functions and hiding functions in the baseclass.

Notes:

- I wrote "smart_ptr" intentionally, even though you wrote shared_ptr, because for this particular example, using `auto_ptr` (C++98) or `unique_ptr` (C++11) would be a better choice since no references are shared.
- When implementing `clone()`, I would also `assert()` that the pointer returned by `do_clone()` is non-null and that it points to the same dynamic type as `this` using `typeid`. If that assertion fires, someone forgot to override `do_clone()` in a derived class.
- You can not return the derived type in the baseclass, because that would require a dependency cycle and because it is not at all sure that the base object is also a derived object.
- You could create a template function that you would pass the expected type and which then `dynamic_cast`s to the requested type, I'll leave that decision to you. The syntax would then be like `derived* derived_ptr = base_ptr->execute<derived>()`, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, would clone function not invoke a copy constructor? My hope was to avoid copying the object and simply give it the ability to generate const pointers to itself, so that other objects can use them via pre-defined interfaces... Also the reason I used shared_ptr was that I wanted to share the pointer to the object via multiple 'pipeline connections' to it.

Comment: The typical idea of the clone function is to clone (i.e. copy the object). This was used as an example only, in the hope that the type issues there can be translated to your problems.

Comment: re "are not covariant, they are completely unrelated", I would say they are covariant (since they presumably are) and mostly unrelated at the C++ type system level (again, since they are). the weasel word "mostly" covering the fact there are defined conversions. which are defined precisely because there is a relation at a higher level of abstraction. covariance is not a c++ language feature, although c++ has some very limited support for covariant function results.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I decided to accept your answer. To get it running I needed to create a virtual getPointer() method that returned a shared pointer to TBaseClassType const. For reasons pointed out by Lightness Races in Orbit and Cheers and hth. - Alf I needed to use shared_from_this when returning the pointer. However, I carefully checked the use_count when using the method in quite a complex scenario with multiple segments having a shared pointer to the object and did not see any problems. Nevertheless, I do appreciate that one needs to be careful when using shared_ptr in this scenario.